# How to handle single result from multiple threads?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

Let's say i have few file formats i can read from. eg. xml, yaml and json.
For each format i have specific reader but i do not know until runtime which file was placed so i try to read file with all of these readers. 
This whole process is currently async.

All i want is a proper way to return only 'FileReaderTask' which completed with result.

So far i came with this but i don't like it too much.
**Especially the part where i return null**

```
    public async Task<ReadResponse> Read(string id)
{
  var readerDetails = _readerDetailsRepository.GetAll();
  var tasks = readerDetails.Select(readerDetail => _reader.ReadAsync(readerDetail, id)).ToList();

  foreach (var result in await Task.WhenAll(tasks))
  {
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result)) // only one will have the response !
    {
      return await HandleResponse(_jsonConverter.Convert<ReadResponse>(result), id);
    }
  }
  return null; // ?? seems pretty bad
}
```

Comment: I am a Java programmer, you would do this using Thread.join() to wait for all thread to complete. I see C# has an equivalent, you can look into that.

Comment: does it mean you let every reader have a go on each file and expect all but one to fail?

Comment: @dlatikay: that's what I understood as well. A brute force approach

Comment: @Juan: of course C# has Thread.Join(), but that's the wrong layer. Tasks already provide an abstraction on top of Threads.

Comment: @ThomasWeller ok

Comment: How long will it take for the readers to figure out that the format is invalid? In JSON, you likely know that after 2 characters. This will take µs only. Same for XML. All your multithreading is unnecessary. Better do it in a regular loop. Please read about a concept called Chain of Responsibility

Comment: The trap you fell into is called Premature Optimization. Before optimizing code and making it multithreadde, please use a performance profiler to tell whether or not you have a performance issue.

Comment: @ThomasWeller, thanks, actually i know about chain of responsibility but i don't want the overhead in implementing it in here. All i want to be able to return once i have not empty result.

Comment: @ThomasWeller, read from file is an example. Real task takes at least few seconds and can or cannot return value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your process is asynchronous, but it is not using multiple threads.In this case it is a good thing, because the threads reading the same file would be competing with each other.

Your current approach uses `WhenAll`, which waits for all tasks to complete before picking the result. This is fine, assuming that all failing tasks complete first. You don't have to wait for all tasks, and process them as they complete instead:

```
var tasks = readerDetails.Select(readerDetail =>
    _reader.ReadAsync(readerDetail, id).ConfigureAwait(false)
).ToList();
foreach (var task in tasks) {
    var result = await task;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result)) {
        return await HandleResponse(_jsonConverter.Convert<ReadResponse>(result), id);
    }
}
```

The loop awaits individual tasks one-by-one, so if the successful task completes ahead of an unsuccessful one, your code wouldn't wait for completion of the remaining tasks before handling the response.

Comment: Why shouldn't all tasks be scheduled on different threads out of the thread pool? Of course the algorithm would wait until they are all finished

Comment: @ThomasWeller Because of resource contention: all threads would be reading the same file at the same time.

Comment: They read out of a string. A string is immutable. All threads can read at the same time

Comment: Hmm, ok. We actually don't know what kind of reseource there is.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight the resource is json string.

Comment: @eugeneK I don't get it, are you saying `_reader.ReadAsync` reads from a JSON string that is already in memory, not from a file?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, _reader.ReadAsync reads for 'very large' file on disk while the specification for the reader defined by ReaderDetails

Comment: @eugeneK So then the shared file is the resource for which multiple threads would compete.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, Right, how i deal with return null ?

Comment: @eugeneK The way your question shows, i.e. `if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))`